# angular - displaying details in mat-table - problem creating multiple tables in multiple records

Tags: json, angular

I have a code structure in angular html as follows.
It creates more than one table when more than one record arrives, how can I prevent this?

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of materialsDetails" >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let subItem of item.materialDemandDetails">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="materialsDetails" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{subItem.id}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

I get the data, I transfer it to the table, but more than one "ID" field occurs as in the bottom picture, how can I prevent this?

I want to show data in material Demand Details in table. but too many columns occur

```
[
  {
    "description": "Ram demand.",
    "createdUserId": "12345",
    "createdUserName": "creater",
    "status": "idle",
    "companyId": 2,
    "materialDemandId": 0,
    "materialDemandDetails": [
      {
        "stockName": "Ram 12 gb products",
        "totalDemand": 2,
        "materialDemandId": 1,
        "productId": 2,
        "id": 1,
        "createdDate": "2022-02-08T14:29:11.1763481",
        "updatedDate": "2022-02-08T11:28:42.409",
        "totalCount": 0,
        "companyId": 0
      },
      {
        "stockName": "Ram 2 gb products",
        "totalDemand": 2,
        "materialDemandId": 1,
        "productId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "createdDate": "2022-02-08T14:32:09.7305862",
        "updatedDate": "2022-02-08T11:28:42.409",
        "totalCount": 0,
        "companyId": 0
      }
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "createdDate": "2022-02-08T14:28:33.0658772",
    "updatedDate": "2022-02-08T11:27:46.939",
    "totalCount": 0
  }
]
```

A json data is coming as below

[Master json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPnIQ.png)

[details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzcKD.png)

[mat-table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE5RG.png)

Models .

```
import {MaterialDemandDetailsModel} from "./material-demand-details-model/material-demand-details-model";

export class MaterialDemandWithDetailModel {
  id: number | undefined;
  description: string | undefined;
  createdUserId: string | undefined;
  createdUserName: string | undefined;
  status: string | undefined;
  companyId: string | undefined;
  totalCount: number | undefined;

  materialDemandDetails: MaterialDemandDetailsModel[] | any; //MaterialDemandDetailsModel[] | undefined;
}


export class MaterialDemandDetailsModel {
  id: number | undefined;
  totalDemand: number | undefined;
  stockName: string | undefined;
  materialDemandId: number | undefined;
  productId: number | undefined;
  createdDate:Date | undefined;
  updatedDate: Date | undefined;
}
```

Comment: check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-material-nested-tables Or https://angularquestions.com/2020/11/16/displaying-nested-array-with-mat-table/

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed this issue before, but it did not give me a solution. So I can show the parent table as I want, but I cannot show the "materialDemandDetails" part in the table.

Comment: I want to show below foo_chaind in the table as shown in the example

Comment: Do you want to only show the `id`  of  `materialDemandDetails` in the parent table or do you want to show all the properties of `materialDemandDetails`?

Comment: I want to show the contents of material Demand Details. so I want to show the incoming data as an array  @MernaMustafa

Comment: `materialDemandDetails: MaterialDemandDetailsModel[] | any;` I want to show data in table

Comment: You can flatten your Array so that only, one iteration is run for one row, from `materialDemandDetails` which fields do you require to display?

Comment: ok, but i don't know how i can do it i am new to angular. Can you give an example on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the second `*ngFor` and change data source to `materialDemandDetails` instead of `materialsDetails`. Change `subItem.id` also to `element.id`.
You don't have to iterate through materialDemandDetails array, but give this array as data source for your table as:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of materialsDetails" >
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="item.materialDemandDetails" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
  </div>
```

stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-responsive-zepz3z?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html
[image: screen shot]

Comment: yes, I did as you said, but it gives an error like this, I think I'm doing something wrong because it's a list.  `Error: src/app/components/MaterialDemand/material-details/material-details.component.html:62:21 - error TS2322: Type 'MaterialDemandDetailsModel[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CdkTableDataSourceInput<MaterialDemandDetailsMod
el>'.`

Comment: very thanks. now running :)